# URLSpan on the TextView In the ListView

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have developed a Thread BBS app.
I use ListView for Thread. ListView has some TextViews, And a TextView has some Clickable URLSpan.

---

textview1 myname

textview2 message message message.
body http://google.co.jp/
body message message message.

---

I want to action below, but I cannot.

When I tap the row except urlspan(link), onListItemClick event has been occurred.
When I tap the urlspan, onListItemClick event hasn't been occurred and URLSpan's OnClick event has been occurred.

I write below code at ArrayAdapter for ListView.

```
Spanned html = Html.fromHtml(body, new EmojiGetter(mContext), null);
SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(html);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(http://google.co.jp/)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(spannable);
while(m.find()){
    MyUrlSpan myUrlSpan = new MyUrlSpan("http://google.co.jp/", m.group(1));
    spannable.setSpan(myUrlSpan, m.start(1), m.end(1), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
holder.body.setText(spannable, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
holder.body.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
holder.body.setFocusable(false);
holder.body.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

But when I tap on textview2, onListItemClick event has not been occurred.

How can I realize this action?